# Expected value and variance of $\frac {X - \overline X}{s}$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Given a finite probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F = \mathcal P(\Omega), \mathbb P)$ and $X, X_i \in L^\infty(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P, [0, 1])$ ($i = 1, \ldots, N$) iid random variables, what can we say about either the expectation or the variance of $Z = \frac {X-\overline X}s$, where:
$$\overline X = \frac 1N\sum_{j=1}^NX_j$$
$$s = \left(\frac 1{N-1}\sum_{j=1}^N(X_j-\overline X)^2\right)^{1/2}$$

It is obvious that $\mathbb E[X-\overline X] = 0$ since $X$ and the $X_i$'s are independent, but I don't know how to find the value of $\mathbb EZ$, hence I can't find $\text{Var}Z$ either.

For a bit of motivation, I'd like to use Chebyshev's inequality to find an upper bound for $\mathbb P[|X-\mathbb EX| \geq k\sqrt {\text{Var}X}]$ but I don't know anything about neither $\mathbb EX$ nor $\text{Var}X$. Therefore I would like to replace these values by their sample counterpart, i.e. use $Z$ instead and find $k'$ such that:
$$\mathbb P\left[|X-\mathbb EX| \geq k\sqrt {\text{Var}X}\right] = \mathbb P[|Z| \geq k'].$$

And actually, I don't really know how to put this: should I consider $\overline X$ and $s$ as constants (in which case it all becomes easy and $k' = k$) or should I consider them as random events that therefore change my probability distribution?